# How to divide a pandas pivot table by a dataframe with a difference shape?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

**Objective:** I have a pivot table, where I would like to divide each cell by a value from my dataframe, if there is a match. 
[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Specifically, all the cells in the column 0 should be divided by 4 because Store1 is 4 in the dataframe.  Similarly, the last column would be divided by 3.
 **The expected outcome is...**
[image: ![enter image description here]

**Data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start':['Store1','Store1','Store1','Store2','Store2','Store2','Store3','Store3','Store3'],
'Stop':['Store1','Store2','Store3','Store1','Store2','Store3','Store1','Store2','Store3'],
'Distance':[0,100,200,100,0,100,100,100,0]}).pivot(columns='Start', index = 'Stop', values=None)

df_div = pd.DataFrame({'Distance':['Store1','Store3'],'Import':[4,3]})
df_div = df_div.set_index('Distance')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with a **for** loop:

```
for store in df_div.index:
    divider = df_div.loc[store,][0]
    df.loc[:,(slice(None),store)] = df.loc[:,(slice(None),store)]/divider
```

Output of *df*:

```
       Distance                  
Start    Store1 Store2     Store3
Stop                             
Store1      0.0    100  33.333333
Store2     25.0      0  33.333333
Store3     50.0    100   0.000000
```

If you want to include only stores from *df_div* in *df*, you can use this outside the for loop:

```
df = df.loc[:,(slice(None),list(df_div.index))]
```

Comment: This solution works if I have matching stores on the df and pivot. Unfortunately, that's not the case. How can I include only columns with matches?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to select stores from df_div? I've edited my solution.